# Matlab treatment of numerical expression

Tags: matlab

Why does Matlab display 1.0000 when entering 1-10^(-16) but 1 when entering 1-10^(-17)? Is there any difference in floating point treatment or is anything else? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, MATLAB can only store 16 significant digits.

MATLAB uses [IEEE 754 double-precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) numbers, which can represent ~16 decimal digits. In this format, 1-10^-16 is stored as:

```
0x3fefffffffffffff
```

The next double after this is:

```
0x3ff0000000000000
```

which just so happens to be `1`. In other words, it's not possible for MATLAB to represent `1-10^17` exactly, so it rounds it to the nearest number it can represent, which turns out to be `1`.

Comment: Related to this, see the [`eps`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) function

Comment: See [MATLAB: Floating-Point Numbers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html) for further discussion of floating point precision as it applies to MATLAB